# Can we add Events without extending Ext.util.Observable?

Tags: extjs

If I define an extjs class and i want to say addEvents inside the initComponent, is it mandatory that the class extend the Ext.util.Observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Observable is now a mixin, so you can use:

```
Ext.define('MyClass', {
    extend: 'SomeOtherClass',
    mixins: ['Ext.util.Observable']
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a brief idea about what is the use of Mixins? I read the sencha docs http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-class-system but the part on mixins was not clear. i.e what is the benefit of mixin?

Comment: I'm not sure I can write it better than [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506210/whats-the-difference-between-mixin-and-extend-in-javascript-libraries)..