# What's the difference between a mixin and an intersection type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Looking at the TypeScript docs and trying out examples for [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and [Mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) *in TypeScript* using the utility methods provided, I'm seeing essentially identical behavior and outcome from both methodologies. I'm ending up with an object in the end that is a combination of 1..n other `types`, `Interfaces`, or `Classes`. Here are the methods I used in my coding samples and are stright from the TypeScript docs.

This is used to apply `mixins` in TypeScript:

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            Object.defineProperty(derivedCtor.prototype, name, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name));
        });
    });
}
```

This is what I used for the `intersection type`:

```
function extend<First, Second>(first: First, second: Second): First & Second {
    const result: Partial<First & Second> = {};
    for (const prop in first) {
        if (first.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            (<First>result)[prop] = first[prop];
        }
    }
    for (const prop in second) {
        if (second.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            (<Second>result)[prop] = second[prop];
        }
    }
    return <First & Second>result;
}
```

Aside from the fact that the `mixins` method takes an array, and the `intersection type` method specifically takes 2 values, they in the end from a behavior standpoint act identically. If I have a `Person` and `User` class each with separate properties and methods, after using either method above, I have the ability to create a new instance from either the type defined from the `intersection type` or `mixin` and see the combination of everything from both `Person` and `User`.

Ironically this is exactly what I want, but I feel I'm missing a purpose of *when* to use either. I did some digging and found this post related to JavaScript (
[What's the difference between mixin() and extend() in Javascript libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506210/whats-the-difference-between-mixin-and-extend-in-javascript-libraries)) but I'm not sure if `extend` in this case is identical to an `intersection type` in TypeScript (even though the helper method is called just that).

Looking at both helper methods they *appear* to copy or define properites from A to B exactly as desired. Can someone please explain the difference between the 2 in TypeScript and why one method would be used over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give my two cents.

**Mixins** are meant to alter the class definition adding functionalities given by other object(s). They work on the prorotype, so the effect is performed against all the instances, both already made **and** the future ones.

**Intersections** are meant to extend the properties of **one given instance** without altering the original one. In fact, the returned object is a brand new instance

```
const result: Partial<First & Second> = {};
```

so the difference is huge in my opinion. Without working on the prototype, what is given is just a single, disposable instance. Instances of the same class won't be affected by the change, as none is reflected in the class prototype.