# Viable method to do Multiple Inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I found this post about inheritance in javascript which I think is one of the best I've found on the web but this post can't be use for Multiple Inheritance because it will override the prototype methods and variables of past Super Class

ref : [Javascript inheritance: call super-constructor or use prototype chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152931/javascript-inheritance-call-super-constructor-or-use-prototype-chain/4389429#4389429)

**I would like to know if there's a way to do multiple inheritance with the principle of the "surrogate constructor" (see stack overflow ref post).**

I've tried this method and I think it works great but I would like other opinions about limition, if there is, about this implementation.

You'll need jQuery to run this or just use this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NGr2L/

```
Function.prototype.extend = function(p_parent){ 
    function ctor() {};
    //My trick for the Multiple Inheritance is to use the jQuery.extend method
    ctor.prototype = $.extend({}, this.prototype, p_parent.prototype);
    this.prototype = new ctor();
    // I commentd this line of the reference post answer
    //because it created multiple constructor which I found confusing
    //this.prototype.constructor = this;
}

var Color = (function(){
    //Constructor
    function Color (p_color){
        //Priviligied
        this.color = p_color;
        //Private
        //...
    };

    //Public
    Color.prototype.GetFormattedColor = function(){
        return "I'm " + this.color;
    };

    return Color;
})();

var Animal = (function(){
    //Constructor
    function Animal (p_name){
        //Priviligied
        this.name = p_name;
        //Private
        //...
    };

    //Public
    Animal.prototype.GetFormattedName = function(){
        return "my name is " + this.name;
    };

    return Animal;
})();

var Tiger = (function(){
    //Constructor
    function Tiger (p_name, p_color, p_kindOfTiger){
        //Base constructor
        Color.call(this, p_color);
        Animal.call(this, p_name);

        //Priviligied
        this.kindOfTiger = p_kindOfTiger;
        //Private
        //...
    };
    //Inheritance
    Tiger.extend(Color); //I know, I could've loop 
    Tiger.extend(Animal);// on the "extend()" arguments to do this in one call

    //Public
    Tiger.prototype.GetTiger = function(){
        return "I'm a " + this.kindOfTiger + ", " + 
                                            this.GetFormattedName() + " and " + 
                                            this.GetFormattedColor()
    };

    return Tiger;
})();

var myTiger = new Tiger("Boris", "Aqua", "bengal tiger");
myTiger.GetTiger();
```

Thank you very much

Comment: The first significant drawback i can think of is that with this code you have no easy way to check if Tiger is an Animal/Color. I will return with a more pertinent answer when i get the time.

Comment: You're right, this is indeed a problem. Thanks for your time !

Comment: Have you thought about a better solution yet ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way of implementing multiple inheritance is composition.

Let's say we have a class `Orange` which extends (inherits from) classes `Fruit` and `Color`. Each of the 2 classes will have their own constructors and methods.

The main problem with multiple inheritance is that the methods in parent classes **may collide**.

```
function Colour(shade) {
    this.shade = shade;
}
Colour.prototype.describe = function() {
    console.log('Colour of shade', this.shade);
}

function Fruit(type) {
    this.type = type;
}
Fruit.prototype.describe = function() {
    console.log('Fruit of type', this.type);
}

function Orange() {}
Orange.prototype.describe = function() {
    this.constructor.describe(); // which describe to call?
    console.log('Orange');
}

multipleExtend(Orange, [Fruit, Colour]);
```

To avoid namespace collisions, the best way out is to **use composition over inheritance**.

```
function Orange() {
    this._colour = new Colour('orange');
    this._fruit = new Fruit('orange');
}
Orange.prototype.describe = function() {
    this._colour.describe();
    this._fruit.describe();
    console.log('Orange');
}
```

A compromise of a solution can be achieved by extending one class and composing the other - but the choice of which classes to extend and which ones to compose may not be *pragmatic*.

**PS: Inheriting and extending means the same thing (preventing possible confusions).**

---

### Edit 1

After spending some time on the idea of multiple-inheritance in JS, I came up with a *design* that captures the basic idea.

Unfortunately, I couldn't fit the whole thing in the size of an SO answer, so I made it into [an article](https://medium.com/@zhirzh/multiple-inheritance-in-js-d39244c791a9). You'll see that your "surrogate constructor" is what I call the  `inheritsMultipleConstructors()` function.

Comment: Ok, but the question is specifically about multiple inheritance, not other patterns. What is multipleExtend?

Answer (score -1):

The decision for the most suitable approach has to reflect the relationship of `Color`, `Animal` and `Tiger`. A tiger obviously **is** an animal, both animal and tiger might feature a color (tiger **has** a color). Thus *inheritance* only applies for `Animal <= Tiger`. A `Color` could be acquired by composition. But here *aggregation* will be the more favorable choice. Thus the `Tiger` class **does contain** a `color`field of type `Color`.

Real class based *mutliple inheritance* (inheriting directly from more than one prototype a time) technically is not possible in JS. But **function based *composition*** is a very handy tool as well. For the provided example there will be two additional *behaviors* that not that accidentally feature a `describeThyself` method name each, which already is in use by e.g. some class implementations. Thus in addition to the composition part, the behaviors also need to take care of *conflict resolution*.

For reasons of comfort the provided example code does feature class syntax ...

```js
class Color {
  constructor(colorValue) {
    this.color = colorValue;
  }
  describeThyself() {
    return `I'm colored ${this.color}.`;
  }
}

class Animal {
  constructor(speciesName) {
    this.species = speciesName;
  }
  describeThyself() {
    return `My species is called ${this.species}.`;
  }
}


function withNormalHuntingBehavior() { // function based mixin.
  function describeThyself() {
    return 'I mostly feed on herbivorous mammals.';
  }
  if (this.describeThyself) {                     // - conflict resolution
    this.describeThyself = (function (proceed) {
      return function () {                        // - function composition

        var result = proceed.apply(this/*, arguments*/);
        return (result + ' ' + describeThyself.call(this/*, result, arguments*/));
      }
    }(this.describeThyself));
  } else {
    this.describeThyself = describeThyself;
  }
  return this;
}

function withManEatingBehavior() { // function based mixin.
  function describeThyself() {
    return 'I ocassionally kill and eat humans too.';
  }
  if (this.describeThyself) {                     // - conflict resolution
    this.describeThyself = (function (proceed) {
      return function () {                        // - function composition

        var result = proceed.apply(this/*, arguments*/);
        return (result + ' ' + describeThyself.call(this/*, result, arguments*/));
      }
    }(this.describeThyself));
  } else {
    this.describeThyself = describeThyself;
  }
  return this;
}


class Tiger extends Animal {                // - inheritance part I.
  constructor(subspeciesName, colorValue) {
    super('Tiger');                         // - inheritance part II.
    this.subspecies = subspeciesName;
    this.color = (new Color(colorValue));   // - aggregation.
  }
  describeThyself() {
    return [
      super.describeThyself.call(this),     // - super delegation.
      `I'm of the "${this.subspecies}" subspecies.`,
      `And ${this.color.describeThyself()}` // - forwarding.
    ].join(' ');
  }
}
// - composition at prototype level.
withNormalHuntingBehavior.call(Tiger.prototype);


function createBengalTiger(colorValue) { // bengal tiger factory
  var
    tiger = new Tiger('Bengal Tiger', colorValue);

  // composition at instance level.
  return withManEatingBehavior.call(tiger);
}

var siberianTiger = new Tiger('Siberian Tiger', 'kind of pale orange/reddish-something');
var bengalTiger = createBengalTiger("bright reddish-gold");

console.log('siberianTiger.describeThyself() : ' + siberianTiger.describeThyself());

console.log('bengalTiger.describeThyself() : ' + bengalTiger.describeThyself());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ok, but the question is specifically about multiple inheritance. The specific example from the OP is non-sensensical, but irrelevant.

Comment: @DaveNewton ... you are right ... I'm going to handle the *multiple inheritance* part with an example based on (a) function based mixin(s).