# How can I create custom events for google maps api v3 objects?

Tags: google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

I want to make a specialized type of polygon object that wraps around or inherits from the `google.maps.Polygon` class. I want it to have a custom `edited` event that can be listened to, ideally via the normal `addListener` interface. Can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like JustinY's answer.

An alternative would be manually triggering an event like this:

```
 function CustomPolygon(options) {
     var self = this;
     // initialize any options
     console.log('init')
 }

 function edit() {
     // do work!!!
     // now tell people about it!
     google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'edited');
 }

 // extend CustomPolygon from google.maps.Polygon
 CustomPolygon.prototype = new google.maps.Polygon();
 CustomPolygon.prototype.edit = edit;

 // now you can do 
 var p = new CustomPolygon({ /*options*/
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(p, 'edited', function () {
     document.body.innerHTML = 'edited!';
 });
 p.edit();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/stevejansen/hQZcT/

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

Comment: I didn't know about the event.trigger method. I think I like this better.

Comment: BTW, people recommend not using the `new ParentClass();` method for inheritance in javascript anymore; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152931/javascript-inheritance-call-super-constructor-or-use-prototype-chain

Comment: Thanks, I know about the whole `new` vs. `Object.create()` debate.  The arguments for either seem a bit pedantic to me.  I'm fine working with either technique.

Answer (score 2):

In a Google Developers article titled [Fun with MVC](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun) we find two ways to do this.

1. In the [Binding Properties](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun#bindingproperties) section we learn that whenever the `set(property, value)` method is called on an `MVCObject`, a magic `property_changed` function is called (if present).

   ```
   // Prints "something changed to ftw!!!"
   myObject.something_changed = function(){
     console.log('something changed to ' + this.get('something'));
   }
   myObject.set('something', 'ftw!!!');
   ```
2. In the [Outputting Information](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun#outputtinginformation) section we learn of that the less mystical `addListener()` method can also be used for listening to changes in values with `set()`. The following code snippet does the exact same thing as the code above.

   ```
   // Prints "something changed to ftw!!!"
   myObject.addListener('something_changed', function(){
     console.log('something changed to ' + this.get('something'));
   }
   myObject.set('something', 'ftw!!!');
   ```

I prefer method #2 because it involves less black magic.

Comment: Thanks you for sharing your knowledge, but it seems that you've asked this questions for the only reason to provide your own answer. So when you're not interested in answers it would be fair when you save the time of the users that like to give a answer and place a notice about that in the question.

Comment: However, when you want to create a "class" that inherits from another "class", using the prototype (as posted in Steve Jansen's answer) is the better approach, because with your attempt you have to define the custom event for each single instance.

Comment: @Dr.Molle - answering your own question is acceptable, and Justin doesn't need to add anything to the question to explain that's his intention: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: He don't need to explain his intention, but it would be fair when he would do it, to save the time of other users that would start to answer a question where no answer is wanted.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I answered the question at the same time I posted it; there was no possibility for someone to see the question without my answer.