# Change Polygon fillColor - only selected polygon and clear previous selections (google maps v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have polygons, multi polygons,and polygons with holes in them. All them working fine. We are currently putting a pin (Marker) and then moving the marker when someone selects a different polygon. 
[Edit: There are hundreds of polygons, so manually re-setting them like in the answer below is not practical]

What we want is to replace the marker with a fillColor. When someone clicks on a polygon I can easily change the fillColor - that's not an issue. The problem I am having is trying to clear that fillColor, when someone clicks a different polygon.

This is a large project with many files... But the relevant portion is here:

```js
//building is the polygon
building.addListener('click', function() {

  // We've been using markers, can we can easily move them.
  setMarker(map, this.center, true);

  // Want to use this instead. This works fine to color the polygon but...
  this.setOptions({
    fillColor: 'orange'
  });

  // I need some function, likely to be called here that clears any other polygon that has been change to 'orange'.
  // I was looking at  map.data.revertStyle(); but this doesn't work at this level. 

});
```

Just to make it clear, there are plenty of examples of how to reset the polygon if someone clicks on it again. That is easy to do. I want to reset when a different polygon is clicked, just like how the move marker functionality works.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we ended up approaching this. If someone has a better solution, feel free to pass it along. This might help some people though...
I am creating a separate polygon, which will only hold the last polygon clicked. It gets reset on click on any other polygon. The pros is that it works nicely and exactly as needed. The part I don't love is that I am creating a separate layer, and it would be nice to just change the fillColor if possible.

```js
var new_polygon = '';

// Checks for an "active" polygon, clears it if it exists, or sets a new one if it does not.
function active_polygon(center, polygon_latlng) {
  if (new_polygon) {
    new_polygon.setMap(null);
    new_polygon = '';
  }

  new_polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    paths: polygon_latlng,
    fillColor: "#DC4405",
    center: center,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    clickable: true,
    zIndex: 400,
  });

  return new_polygon.setMap(map);
}

//  this was my original listener above for polygons
// This is located in the polygon loop in a later part of the code.
building.addListener('click', function() {

  // Generates the new polygon active later
  active_polygon(this.center, this.getPaths());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `map` listen to a custom `resetColor` event, and trigger this event on the click function of your polygons like this:

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  //initialize map...

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygons paths.

  // Construct the polygon.

  //add polygons to map

  //attach the map to our custom -resetColor- event
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "resetColor", function(){
    resetColor.call(bermudaTriangle, null); //invoke resetColor making sure 'this' is the bermuda triangle
    resetColor.call(secondTriangle, null); // 'this' is the second triangle
    resetColor.call(someOtherTriangle, null); // ditto
  });

  bermudaTriangle.addListener("click", selectedColor); //polygon1
  secondTriangle.addListener("click", selectedColor); //polygon2
  someOtherTriangle.addListener("click", selectedColor); //polygon3
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

function resetColor() {
  console.log("in trigger function");
  this.setOptions({
    fillColor: "black"
  });
}
function selectedColor() {
  //function executed on polygon click
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resetColor"); //trigger our custom event on the map
  this.setOptions({
    fillColor: "yellow" //make the clicked polygon 'selected'
  });
}
```

see [this pen](https://codepen.io/valecarlos/pen/MvwERw?editors=0011) to see it working.

This code above is open for improvement and any idea is welcomed.

Comment: While this technically works - thanks, it's not practical for most applications. We have hundreds of polygons for example and explicitly calling each would be a nightmare.

Comment: I did think about it and the solution is to create your own implementation/extension of the google.maps.Polygon like they suggest in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321157/how-can-i-create-custom-events-for-google-maps-api-v3-objects), following the same idea of the events. The code above is by no means a production-ready code, it was just to give you a simple working example that would put you in the right direction