# isPrototypeOf says no, but instanceof says yes – what's going on?

Tags: javascript

I tried doing some simple type checking for errors, and had the following code:

```
function isError(x) {
  return Error.isPrototypeOf(x)
}
```

However, if I call the function with an instance of an error, I get `false`, like so:

```
isError(new RangeError) // false
```

So I fired up node (well, [io.js](http://iojs.org) anyway), and did the following:

```
> Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(new RangeError))
[Error]
```

In the end, if I do a check with `instanceof`, it works, like so:

```
> (new RangeError) instanceof Error
true
```

So, what exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instanceof` looks at the `.prototype` property (i.e. not `[[Prototype]]`/`__proto__`) of the specified constructor function for you  (i.e. it does some additional work).

`isPrototypeOf` doesn't work as hard and requires you to specify the exact object instance you want to check for on the prototype chain.

```
Error.isPrototypeOf(r = new RangeError); // false.
```

`false` because the function `Error` does not sit on the prototype chain of `r`. The prototype chain of `r` is:

`r` => `RangeError.prototype` (an **instance** of `Error`) => `Error.prototype` (an **instance** of `Object`))

Nowhere on this chain is the `Error` constructor function, hence false.

If we modify your example like so:

```
Error.prototype.isPrototypeOf(r = new RangeError); // true.
```

This returns true because the `.prototype` property of the `Error` function **is** on the prototype chain of `r`.

Comment: Is really `RangeError.prototype` an instance of `Error`?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Yes, I believe it is. If you know better, please let me know.

Comment: I do not know better. I am just asking. :-) Isn't it that it's `RangeError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype)` rather than `RangeError.prototype = new Error()`?

Comment: OK, I hadn't considered that subtle distinction. Is it even possible to find out the answer? What you are highlighting is an implementation-related distinction.

Comment: I guess not possible. It really depends on how we define "instance". Nevermind my question, I'm just trying to get some things straight in my mind. :-)

Answer (score 7):

[`isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) and `getPrototypeOf` look at the prototype chain directly, while [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) looks at the `.prototype` property of the given constructor function. You need to use:

```
function isError(x) {
  return Error.prototype.isPrototypeOf(x)
}
```

Your function tests whether `x` inherits from the `Error` constructor *function object*.

Comment: But it's easier to just use `instanceof`?

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. This lead me to try something else: `Object.getPrototypeOf(Error).isPrototypeOf(new RangeError)` returns false, while `Error.prototype.isPrototypeOf(new RangeError)` returns true – what's going on here?

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(new Error()).isPrototypeOf(new RangeError)` returns true, you have to understand the the difference between the prototype property of constructors, and the prototype of instances, usually the `__proto__`

Comment: That is, `Object.getPrototypeOf(Error)` is `Function.prototype`, because you're asking for the protoype of a function (constructor)

Comment: Of course, this makes sense. Not enough coffee today I think (or too much!) Thank you very much for the insight!

Comment: @al-Zami: First of all, there is no relationship established by doing `Parent.apply(this)`; you'll need to actually [set up the prototype chain](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10898859/1048572). Second, there is no constructor set to anything, `.constructor` is just a property inherited from the prototype object. Lastly, sorry for the confusion; I didn't mean to say that `instanceof` looks at the `.constructor` property of the given instance (which it does not), but that `instanceof` is given a constructor to look at.

Comment: @al-Zami See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152931/javascript-inheritance-call-super-constructor-or-use-prototype-chain/4389429#4389429