# Javascript object creation confusion with this keyword and prototype property

Tags: javascript, this, self

I try to create a javascript object as follows

```
var SuperObj = function(){
    this.super = "super from Super";
    this.prototype.getSuper = function(){
        return this.super;
   }
}
```

the code above throw errors:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'getSuper' of undefined

However when I tried the following code it worked.

```
var SuperObj = function(){
    this.super = "super from Super";
    SuperObj.prototype.getSuper = function(){
        return this.super;
    }
}
```

I want to know the difference. I think in the first case, both 'this' share the same execute environment. How come we can use it to add property but not function in prototype property?

Comment: You should probably declare the prototype Outside the constructor. Only declare instanced data with 'this' inside it. So something like: `var SuperObj = function(){this.super = "super from Super";}; SuperObj.prototype.getSuper = function(){return this.super;};`

Answer (score 1):

`SuperObj.prototype` and `this.prototype` are not the same things. There is no default property called `prototype` on object instances.

The following will do what you are trying to do

```
var SuperObj = function(){
  this.super = "super from Super";
  // Here, this.constructor === SuperObj
  this.constructor.prototype.getSuper = function(){
      return this.super;
  }
}
```

Having said all that, I have never found a valid case for setting prototype properties during construction. Prototype properties are set once, object properties are set with every constructor. See [Javascript inheritance: call super-constructor or use prototype chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152931/javascript-inheritance-call-super-constructor-or-use-prototype-chain/4389429#4389429)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new object instance you can't access to *prototipe* property because doesn't exist any one.

If you want to access to the prototype property through *this* you have to use the following pattern:

```
this.constructor.prototype.method
```