# Javascript sub classing, super constructors and using custom extend loses base class methods

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascript-inheritance

In another SO question about whether to call a super-constructor or use the prototype chain the answer provided by one of the users seemed sensible but didn't work for me when I implemented it on my solution which has multiple layers of inheritance.

Here's the answer I'm referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4389429/392591

So I've created a jsFiddle using this custom extend method to illustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/68q7yghv/
I've added the jsFiddle code at the bottom.

In my test I've created a 4 tier class inheritance structure from baseClass through to subSubSubClass each of which (except the baseClass) use the 'extend' method to inherit from the previous sub-class. When you hit the test button I'm printing out *class*.baseClassMethod to see if it finds it, but it only finds it for the base class.

You should see the following results: 
function () { this.output += "baseClassMethod"; }
undefined
undefined
undefined

**Is it possible that the cause is that the call to the super constructor is messing with the 'this' context?**

```
function extend(baseClass, subClass) {
  var originalPrototype = subClass.prototype;
  subClass.prototype = Object.create(baseClass.prototype);
  for (var key in originalPrototype) {
    subClass.prototype[key] = originalPrototype[key];
  }
  subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
  Object.defineProperty(subClass.prototype, 'constructor', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: subClass
  });
};

var baseClass = function() {
  this.output = "Base: ";
  this.toggleWizardHandlers = [];
  this.baseClassMethod = function() {
    this.output += "baseClassMethod";
  };
};

baseClass.prototype.on = function(eventName, handler) {
  switch (eventName.toLowerCase()) {
    case "togglewizards":
      return this.toggleWizardHandlers.push(handler);
      break;
  }
};

baseClass.prototype.toggleWizards = function(newWizard, newStepIndex) {
  var handler, i, len, ref;
  ref = this.toggleWizardHandlers;
  for (var i = 0; i < ref.length; i++) {
    handler = ref[i];
    setTimeout(handler, 0, newWizard, newStepIndex);
  }
};

var subClass = function() {
  baseClass(this);
};
extend(baseClass, subClass);

var subSubClass = function() {
  subClass(this);
};
extend(subClass, subSubClass);

var subSubSubClass = function() {
  subSubClass(this);
};
extend(subSubClass, subSubSubClass);

var manager = function(settings) {

  this.log = function(message) {
    $("#log").html($("#log").html() + "<br />" + message);
  };
  this.clearLog = function() {
    $("#log").html("");
  };

  this.testBaseClass = new baseClass();
  this.testSubClass = new subClass();
  this.testSubSubClass = new subSubClass();
  this.testSubSubSubClass = new subSubSubClass();

  //test.on("toggleWizards", function(param) {    that.log(param);  });
};

$(function() {
  var manage = new manager("");

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    manage.log("start test");
    manage.clearLog();

    try {
      manage.log(manage.testBaseClass.baseClassMethod);
    } catch (e) {
      manage.log(e);
    }

    try {
      manage.log(manage.testSubClass.baseClassMethod);
    } catch (e) {
      manage.log(e);
    }

    try {
      manage.log(manage.testSubSubClass.baseClassMethod);
    } catch (e) {
      manage.log(e);
    }

    try {
      manage.log(manage.testSubSubSubClass.baseClassMethod);
    } catch (e) {
      manage.log(e);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prototype inheritance is working, you can try to access `on` or `toggleWizards` on all your instances.

Your super calls in the constructors lack a crucial part though: [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). Without it, you are passing `this` for the first parameter, not as the `this` argument. Your base class is not able to initialise any properties on the subclass instance without this:

```
function subClass() {
    baseClass.call(this);
//            ^^^^
}
```

Comment: if my base class had an argument (e.g. exchange rate) but in the subSubClass you still want to call subClass.call(this), is it appropriate to ALSO make a call to baseClass.call(this, 0.45)?  
I'm not sure what happens if you call both base constructors.

Comment: Not a good idea. `SubSubClass` should only call `SubClass` and `SubClass` should only call `BaseClass`. If `BaseClass` takes an argument, all subclasses (that don't use a constant for it) will need to take an argument as well and pass it through.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the super constructor, you need to use `apply`, not call it as a simple function.

```
var subClass = function() {
    baseClass.apply(this);
};
```

Otherwise your sub-classes new `this` object is passed as the first argument to the super constructor and `this` will refer to the global object (or null in strict mode).

A small thing, it common to Capitalise constructor functions so that its clear that they should be called with `new` and not as regular functions.

Comment: The copying is fine, it's from `originalPrototype` not from `baseClass.prototype`

Comment: @mcfedr I'm using this form of extending because I was having trouble with subClass.prototype = new baseClass(), which fires the constructor twice; I switched to subClass.prototype = Object.create(baseClass), but then I wanted to be able to call super constructors and for some reason it seemed a good way to go. Using the Object.createObject approach, can you still call the superconstructors, get access to baseClass properties and methods? Is there anything missing from this approach?

Comment: Your use of `Object.createObject` is completely fine. The only problem is that you are calling the super constructor as a function. If you change to `apply` or `call` you set `this` value for the super constructor, so when that constructor adds values to `this` they are added to the same object as you are seeing in the sub class constructor.