# Create a javascript base class object from an inherited instance

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype, radix

I'm using the accepted answer here to implement inheritance: [Javascript inheritance: call super-constructor or use prototype chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152931/javascript-inheritance-call-super-constructor-or-use-prototype-chain).  So I have a Class B that inherits from Class A.  Class B has properties/functions on it's prototype exclusive to Class B objects.

EDIT: to be more clear, I've already setup the inheritance chain, that's not what I need help with.  The objects are defined like this:

```
function classA() {
    this.name= '';
    this.sex = '';
}

function classB(){
  classA.call(this, arguments);
  this.age= 0;
}
```

In my code, i've created a new Class B object and set some properties:

```
var _b = new ClassB();
_b.name = 'mike';   -- name is a property of ClassA
_b.sex = 'none';    -- sex  a property of ClassA
_b.age = 20;        -- age is only a property of Classb
```

I'm calling an API that will only accept an object of "type" ClassA.  So I need to create a ClassA object and set all it's properties to the values coming from _b, but only the properties that are properties of ClassA.

In this example, the newly created ClassA object will be this:
    {
    name: 'mike',
    sex: 'none'
    }

Is there a way to do this without explicitly setting each property?

```
var _a = new ClassA();
_a.name = _b.name;
_a.sex = _b.sex;
```

I don't want to have to change the code every time I add a new property to ClassA

Comment: You may find this [article](https://medium.com/@PitaJ/javascript-inheritance-patterns-179d8f6c143c#.q4yquhgbm) interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object type is simply determined by the checking/matching keys, creating an adapter is a simple solution. If you are checking prototype to determine Object type, you can instantiate an empty object of that type for *newObj* in the adapter.

```
var foo = {
    a: 'alpha',
    b: 'beta',
};

var bar = {
    a: 'alfa',
    b: 'bravo',
    c: 'charlie'
};

function adapt(objA, objB) {//only copy properties common to objA from objB
    var newObj = {};
    for (var prop in objA) {
        var val = objB[prop];
        newObj[prop] = val;
    }

    return newObj;
}

console.log(adapt(foo, bar));
```

Comment: thanks, yes thats exactly what I need.  I was thinking that I didn't explain it very well, glad you understood.